# Like/unlike system in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, social-networking

I am creating a like dislike system in PHP and mysqli; I am also fetching posts of users followers by joining followers and photos table with the help of uid.  Now I want users to like pictures of followers but I can't get the individual id of a picture. 
This is my code for fetching user's followers pictures:

```
$query = "SELECT photos.image_url,photos.email,photos.username,photos.uid,photos.id FROM photos join followers on photos.uid = followers.user_id where followers.uid = '$id' ORDER BY photos.image_url DESC ";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {

  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
  $follower_email = $row['email'];
  $pics_id = $row['id'];

  while ( $users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {?>

<div class="card" >
  <div class="float">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="<?php echo $avatar_image; ?>" class="avatar">
  </div>
      <div class="username" style="">
      <p><?php echo $users['username']; ?></p>
  </div>
</div>

  <img src="<?php echo $users['image_url']?>" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b><?php echo "<div><a href='users.php?id=".$users['uid']."'>
               <h3>".$users['username']."</h3>
      </div></a>";?></b></h4> 
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
  <input type="submit"  name="like" value="like">

</form>



  </div>
</div>
</div><br>

  <?php }


}
?>
```

and this is my code for inserting likes

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO likes(id,user_id,post_id) VALUES('','$id','$pics_id')";
  $fire = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die();


}


?>
```

and this is my code for where i got all the variables

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {
  $users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
    $pic_id = $users['id'];

  }
  ?>
     <?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
  $id = $row['id'];
}?>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {
  $users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
    $id = $users['id'];
    $fullname = $users['fullname'];
    $avatar_image = $users['avatar_path'];
  }
  ?>
 <?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE email='$email'";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
  $photos_id = $row['id'];
  $photos_uid = $row['uid'];
  $photos_email = $row['email'];

}?>
  <?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id='$id'";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {
  $users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
  $username =  $users['username'];
}
  ?>
     <?php
     $query = "SELECT * FROM followers WHERE id='$id'";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
  $user_id = $row['user_id'];
  $follower_id = $row['follower_id'];
  $uid = $row['uid'];
}
```

and these are my table pics

this is photos table:

[image]

this is followers table:

[image]

this is users table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and query is preventing you from getting correct answers . Make the following changes which will make your query more compact and use prepared sql statements or escape values to prevent injection .

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM photos as 'ph'
          inner join followers as 'fol'
          on fol.user_id = ph.uid
          where fol.uid = '$id'
          ORDER BY ph.image_url DESC ";
```

Now remove these three lines of code

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
$follower_email = $row['email'];
$pics_id = $row['id'];
```

Because the above is not necessary , you can get the same values within the while loop for each of the entry .

In the input type submit , pass a dynamic id to catch the pic id against which the like will be counted like this

```
<input type="submit" id="<?=$users['id'];?>|like" value="like">
```

At the time of like just explode it on the basis of "|" and take the zeroth value of the exploded array to get the pic id . This type of like dislike codes should be best using JQuery / AJAX . I once developed a YouTube like page where likes , votes and positioning of the videos on the basis of votes all were done through JQuery / AJAX and videos were re-arranged according to votes without even page refresh .

Comment: thanx for you reply my main problem is how can i get id column from photos table i cant get id because its auto incrementing and primary key

Comment: Don't worry , use my sql query and write a while loop on the the array of values you will get . At each iteration catch the id which will be the photos id and keep it as the id of the submit button , your problem will be solved .

Comment: Please check with the SQL query that I had written in the answer and let e now if it solves your purpose or not .

Comment: i tried your query and when i choose the id of the post it picks only first id & loops that id in every post so same id is going in database for every post

Comment: The query I have given is against the first query , and you have to pass the dynamic ids on click of the button .

Comment: i can pass dynamic ids of users but how will i pass dynami ids of posts

Comment: In my query you will get all related ids from photos table , which you can pass through the button .

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

Your code seems very insecure. You are neither using prepared sql statements to prevent SQL-Injections nor are you escaping the values in the html output. E.g. `<h3>".$users['username']."</h3>` seems to be insecure against XSS.

My advice:

- use prepared statements
- use a template engine, that has escaping by default (e.g. Twig)

Regarding your problem:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO likes(id,user_id,post_id) VALUES('','$id','$pics_id')";
```

Why are you inserting an empty id here? Shouldn't this be at least some value?

```
action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"
```

This is superflous. Just remove the action if you would like to post to the same url

Where does $id come from? Is it properly set?

```
join followers on photos.uid = followers.user_id
```

Is this join condition correct? I cannot figure out, which column is the right to join, because the names of the columns are not very clear. user_id and uid are basically the same thing in followers table.

It's hard to figure out where the problem comes from. The code is not very well written and there are some things that are not clear to me.

Comment: i inserted an empty id because id column is primary key & is set to autoincrement

Comment: and yes the join statement is correct & is working rightly

Comment: If id is a primary key and auto incremented, you should just leave it out in the insert: `$query = "INSERT INTO likes(user_id,post_id) VALUES('$id','$pics_id')";`

Comment: ok ill do that but i am having problem in getting photos id which are auto incremeting  how can i fetch that id